# C# Entity Framework 7 Linq to Entity check if data exist in multiple table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to identify if a record exists in three tables.

**TableMapping**:

[image: TableMapping:]

**RbMapping**:

[image: RbMapping]

**RgMapping**:

[image]

I am using EF 7 `dbContext` to access these tables.

I have written two samples of LINQ but not sure if it will perform against  large volume of data.

Method 1:

```
bool isExist = dbContext.MappingTable
                  .AsNoTracking()
                  .Where(x => x.mappingCode == 1234)
                  .Any(x => x.RbMappings.Any(y => y.MappingId == x.MappingId && y.RbId == 3)
                            && x.RgMapping.Any(z=> z.MappingId == x.MappingId && z.RgId == 2);
```

Method 2:

```
bool IsExist = (from mp in dbContext.MappingTable
                join rb in dbContext.RbMapping on new
                {
                    JoinProperty1 = mp.MappingId,
                    JoinProperty2 = rbId // Will be input field = 3
                }
                equals new
                {
                    JoinProperty1 = rb.MappingId,,
                    JoinProperty2 = rb.RbId
                }
                join rg in dbCContext.RgMappings on new
                {
                    JoinProperty1 = rb.MappingId,
                }
                equals new
                {
                    JoinProperty1 = rb.MappingId,
                }
                where hs.MappingCode == 1234
                select mp).AnyAsync();
```

Can anyone advise which one will work better for large volumes of data? I'll be running these Linq queries several times.

And these tables are also huge around 4 million records.

Comment: second approach is better in code cleanliness wise and will be a single query executing in both cases, so it is primarily opinion based i think

Comment: Have you checked the generated SQLs? Note that in the first method `y.MappingId == x.MappingId` and `z.MappingId == x.MappingId` conditions are redundant since they are provided by the navigation property used.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad If he add `Any` at the end of the first query and remove the redundant criterias inside, it should produce the same SQL as the second, will be less code and in general using navigation properties instead of joins is the recommended way for writing EF queries.

Comment: **Define** *huge* ... how **many** rows are in those tables?

Comment: Thanks all for commenting I am looking at your suggestions. Table will have around 4 million records..

Comment: @RajGan you can monitor generated queries with `SQL profiler` and just compare query `Execution Plans` using SSMS to make sure which query has a better performace

Comment: @Ivan Stoev Looks like for EF7 its not easy to look for generated SQL. Currently I am started to repository layer code and I am executing via unit test module.hope performance will be not be affected.

Comment: @espiprogramer I am using in-memory currently since its a green field project